# assigning a value from a ajax request in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following piece of jquery code

```
var test = "test";

$.ajax({
    url: root + "/servletPath",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (text) {
        alert(text); // returns the right value
        test = text;

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});

// prints "test" and not the value that should be assigned in the success function
alert(test)
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: You should use the callback function as you have been doing as AJAX runs asynchronously. http://curtistimson.co.uk/jquery/using-jquery-callback-functions/

Answer (score 3):

You're alerting the variable `test` before the value has been assigned. `$.ajax` is asynchronous by default.

**Possible Solution:**

```
var test = "test";

$.ajax({
    url: root + "/servletPath",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (text) {
        test = text;

        alertTest();
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});

function alertTest(){
    alert(test);
};
```

You could also set the `async` property to `false` on the `$.ajax` method, to run the code synchronously.